# Javascript - function with arguments as another function's argument

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I'm trying to pass a function with two arguments as an argument to another function (sort of callbacks). I have one function that is unchangeble ("F"), and another that's a wrapper to the former one, and which I can code the way I like ("G"). I tried to simplify the code as much as possible, leaving just the important parts of it:

```
"use strict"

// this function can't be changed in any way
var F = function (a, b)
{
    return new G(function (success, error)
    {
        var sum = a + b;

        if (sum > 0)
        {
            // EXCEPTION: point of failure, since we can't reach G.success
            success(sum);
        }
        else
        {
            // of course we'd fail here too
            error(sum);
        }
    });
};

var G = function (f)
{
    this.success = function (result)
    {
        console.log("The sum is positive: " + result);
    }

    this.error = function (result)
    {
        console.log("The sum is negative: " + result);
    }

    return f();
};

var result = F(10, 5);
```

Comment: Change to `f(this.success, this.error)` ?

Comment: Normally I'd code "G" without using "this", but here I tried to be as simple as posslbile.

Comment: Whether or not you use `this` doesn't matter. I only used it since you were using it. All that matters is: You are creating a two functions inside `G` and it seems you want to pass them to `f`. So that's exactly what you should do.

Comment: You're right, and it works! Please answer the question so I can check it.